# Understanding promise chains

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm using Promises in NodeJS project, and would like to understand Promise.chains better.

I have one exposed function:

Main library function, that I want my users to call. It will return a promise, and the users then need to handle the resolve and reject's.

That Main library function will call many other library functions, which I want to chain. So each of those functions will return a promise like so:

```
mainLibraryFunction = function (arguments...) {
  return this.firstLibraryFn().then(secondLibraryFn).then(thirdLibraryFn)...
}
```

Each of these will return a promise, that can be either reject or resolve. What I would want is that if any of the library functions rejects, then instead passing the reject to the next function, I would like to return the reject out of the MainLibraryFunction. Because otherwise I need to implement the handling of error case for each of the libraryfunctions. Because each of them will get the promise as argument, I would need to check in each of the functions, that did I get resolved or rejected promise as paramater. Then I would need to pass that rejected parameter through all the functions until the last function could then return it out of the MainLibraryFunction. This wouldn't be wise.

So what would be the best practise handling this? Should I add catch in the end of the chain? I heard if I add a catch to the end, it should break the chain even if any of them will reject. Then from the catch, I could return Promise.reject() out of the MainLibraryFunction.

Comment: If you don't handle the error then it will just be returned out of the function and can the be caught by the caller using .catch. If a promise is rejected then the subsequent then calls will only be called if they have an error handler e.g. promise.then(successFn, failureFn)

Comment: NB: that should be `return this.firstLibraryFn().then(...)` - note the parens

Comment: Thanks, I edit it to correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.then` method accepts two arguments: `onFulfilled` and `onRejected`. If you do not supply an `onRejected` callback, this particular `.then` will not be invoked and the chain will fall through to the next handler that implements `onRejected` *or* `.catch`.

```js
Promise.reject()
    .then(() => console.log('onFulfilled 1'))
    .catch(() => console.log('catch 1'));  // will get called

Promise.reject()
    .then(
        () => console.log('onFulfilled 2'),
        () => console.log('onRejected 2')  // will get called
    )
    .catch(() => console.log('catch 2'));  // will not get called
```

As such, no, you won't have to make each function parse their arguments. `secondLibraryFn` etc. will not be called if a promise gets rejected, because they're only defined as the `onFulfilled` handlers. You can safely assume they will be skipped and just add a `.catch` at the end of the chain where you want to catch any and all errors.

Comment: Its worth noting that any `.then()`'s after a `.catch` will be called if the `.catch` doesn't re-reject the promise, good way of recovering from errors.

Comment: In other words, any *error handler* you insert anywhere in the chain (`onRejected` *or* `.catch`) will catch errors up to that point in the chain, after which execution of the chain will continue as usual.